# Is it better to ask gaming puzzles here?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I have a concept of a puzzle to be related to Minecraft, considering [**I**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/264127/mark-giraffe?tab=profile) have quite a huge part in it.

Since it is both a topic in the gaming criteria (Arqade) and it is also supposedly some puzzle (Puzzling SE), which is better to post it at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from browsing [Arqade meta questions with the word "puzzle"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=puzzle), they only allow gaming-related puzzle questions if the puzzles are a part of the game. (E.g. when there's a puzzle-solving minigame) So, probably best to not post there.

We, on the other hand, are perfectly fine with puzzles relating to... basically anything. It's the name of the site, after all. Make sure to tag your question with [video-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) and, assuming that the puzzle itself is good, you're fine.